# How to make table header stretch to full width?

Tags: html, css

I have a table where there are more columns in the table rows than there are in the header:

[image]

How is it possible to make the header stretch to full width, with html/css, but without adding an empty header column ?

My code:

HTML:

```
<div id="thirdTable">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data goes here</td>
        <td>data goes here</td>
        <td>data goes here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>more data here</td>
        <td>more data here</td>
        <td>more data here</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>;
```

CSS:

```
#thirdTable table {
border: none;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
#thirdTable tr {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #0033FF, #3399FF);
}
#thirdTable td {
color: white;
border: none;
padding: 15px 8px 15px 8px;
}
#thirdTable th {
color: #FFCC00;
border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `colspan` attribute:

```
<th colspan="2">Second</th>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `colspan` 
I do not understand why you would want your table to not have all the headers for all the table cells but I assume you would want something like this, where the a `th` can occupy 2 columns or even more if you need.

```css
#thirdTable table {
  border: none;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#thirdTable tr {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #0033FF, #3399FF);
}

#thirdTable td {
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 8px 15px 8px;
}

#thirdTable th {
  color: #FFCC00;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="thirdTable">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>First</th>
        <th colspan="2">Second</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data goes here</td>
        <td>data goes here</td>
        <td>data goes here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>more data here</td>
        <td>more data here</td>
        <td>more data here</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<hr />

<div id="thirdTable">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2">First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>data goes here</td>
        <td>data goes here</td>
        <td>data goes here</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>more data here</td>
        <td>more data here</td>
        <td>more data here</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it's my bad that I didn't explain it well, I'd like the width of the header to always be 100% regardless of how many rows, is it possible to do? I mean it should be dynamic, and always 100%, without having to specify colspan or provide empty rows if possible? Thanks

Comment: @sir-haver I am not sure if that's possible because when you attribute a value to the header, the cell will take that width for itself, making it automatically impossible to stretch the header..